# Not getting click event in an adapter if view not scrolled

Tags: android

This seems to be a very weird issue, I have a recycler view and an adapter set to it with 2 types of view types in it. The adapter has multiple views, buttons in it, and click events on it.

1. The problem is that the click event does not occur until the recycler view is scrolled. Even a little scroll in recycler view and click event starts working.
2. Major problem occurs when there is only a single item in the list, cant be scrolled and so no click events.

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: where you initialize your click event in recycler view?

Comment: Cant share code. @AbdulRafay inside onBindViewHolder

Comment: we couldn't identify your problem without your code snippets follow this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: @AbdulRafay my code matches the snippet, just with data binding included

Comment: Do share your code files